# How Human do you need to be in order to be allowed to use a wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

We see a few part-Humans allowed to use wands and magic.

- Hagrid (1/2 Human, 1/2 Giant)
- Olympe Maxime (1/2 Human, 1/2 Giant)
- Fleur Delacour (3/4 Human, 1/4 Veela)
- Prof. Flitwick (Goblin ancestor)

And other part-Humans not allowed to use wands.

- Centaurs.

What is the distinction that some partial humans are allowed to use wands and others are not? Does it have to do with your ability to pass yourself as Human in the Muggle world?

Comment: [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Centaur) says: "[Centaurs] are their own species, and are not any kind of half-breed."

Comment: Why does Umbridge repeatedly call them half-breeds then?

Comment: *FBAWTFT* says 'The centaur has a human head, torso, and arms joined to a horse’s body which may be any of several colours. Being intelligent and capable of speech, it should not strictly speaking be termed a beast, but by its own request it has been classified as such by the Ministry of Magic.'

Comment: @JackBNimble The wiki continues: "They are not very pleased to be insulted as Professor Umbridge found out to her cost."

Comment: I wonder if Fleur would be allowed a wand if she were 3/4 veela and 1/4 human instead?

Comment: Reference for Flitwick's goblin ancestry: http://web.archive.org/web/20120112040334/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=95

Comment: Umbridge is a bigot who doesn't care about reality, only her prejudices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think so long as they are sufficiently human to be taught Magic and human enough to have magical talent, then they would be allowed in the current HP setting (perhaps not in earlier darker times).

All those examples that are part-human and allowed have human ancestry. Centaurs do not, and I think *that* is the dividing line.

For a full history of what makes a being a 'creature' or 'being' check out *Fantastical Beasts and where to find Them*...I'd reference it, but I've lost my copy.

Comment: But what about muggles?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure at what point someone with dual ancestry is considered "human" enough to be allowed a wand (I know that sounds terrible, but I couldn't think of a better way to word it to reflect canon).

Only humans are allowed to carry wands. There is a law . . . '*clause three of the Code of Wand Use broken for a start. No non-human creature is permitted to carry or use a wand.’*  (*Goblet of Fire* - Amos Diggory - *The Dark Mark*)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a good example list given.

If the non-human ancestor is humanoid, they seem to be allowed a wand.

If the non-human ancestor is an animal, they are not allowed a wand.

It seems a single human parent is sufficient to allow one to use a wand.